# pselect() with accept() in a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, c++11, posix-select

I have a multi-threaded server, which spawns new threads with these loop:

```
 while(handle->m_run) {
    if (handle->m_curThreadCount < handle->m_maxThreads) {
      ready = pselect(socket + 1, &readSocket, NULL, NULL, &timeout, NULL);
      if (ready != 1)
        continue;
      DWORD openedSocket = accept(socket, NULL, NULL);
      handle->m_threads.emplace_back(std::thread(serverThread, openedSocket, handle));
      handle->m_curThreadCount++;
    }
  }
```

Most of the time this works as intended, but occasionally pselect() doesn't fire. I checked it with tcpdump and know, that data is sent to server, so I think it has something to do with main loop.

Also, if run with gdb and broken on pselect() before sending data, pselect() returns 1 as intended.

Is there something wrong with using pselect() this way and how should I fix this?

Comment: What's your timeout argument?

Comment: The code seems weird. `pselect` is posix thing, DWORD is a windows thing. What is your platform? But this would not be the cause of your worries. I myself find poll() much more easy to use.

Comment: You do have timeout. So what happens when timeout expires? What does FD_ISSET tell you?

Comment: Tmeout is 5 seconds, and as i have only one descriptor in fd_set, so I don't use FD_ISSET, as I just need pselect() to return 1. And DWORD is just u_int32_t ypedef, I aim for portabiliy, so i prefer pselect() over linux-only poll().

Comment: I can find no fault in provided code. The only thing which comes to mind is readSocket being not what you expect it to be. As for portability, poll() is not Linux-only, it is Posix. Same way as pselect(). They are equivalent in portability.

Comment: Are you re-setting (readSocket) and (timeout) each time before calling select()?  pselect() may modify these values before it returns, so it usually isn't sufficient to just pass them in again without re-setting them to a known state.  Also, hopefully readSocket is an FD_SET and not an actual socket...?

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy! It really was about resetting fd_set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jeremy Friesner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131930/jeremy-friesner) said, I did not reset fd_set after pselect() had timed out.

Linux Programmer's manual vaguely states:

> On exit, the sets are modified in place to indicate which file descriptors actually changed status.

Adding:

```
FD_ZERO(&readSocket)
FD_SET(socket, &readSocket)
```

before pselect() call solved it.